# replace deprecated parse in script

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

can sonmeone help me replace deprecated parse in script, tried with ast but still dont get any error but it dont return the result just error11.

I belive this is because parse is deprecated, so can anyone help replace it when evaluating?

When i trie to get a result it always return error11

I belive the error is because parse is depretacted but im not sure about that

```
from tkinter import *
import parse
from math import factorial
from OCP.formularios import tabmain3

i = 0
def calc():
    frmcalc = LabelFrame(tabmain3, text="Calculator", padx=5, pady=5, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=2)
    frmcalc.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)


    def get_variables(num):
        global i
        display.insert(i, num)
        i += 1

    def calculate():
        entire_string = display.get()
        print("ddddd "+entire_string)
        try:
            a = parse.expr(entire_string).compile()
            print(a)
            result = eval(a)
            clear_all()
            display.insert(0, result)
        except Exception:
            clear_all()
            display.insert(0, "Error11"). <--- always get this error

    def get_operation(operator):
        global i
        length = len(operator)
        display.insert(i, operator)
        i += length

    def clear_all():
        display.delete(0, END)

    def undo():
        entire_string = display.get()
        if len(entire_string):
            new_string = entire_string[:-1]
            clear_all()
            display.insert(0, new_string)
        else:
            clear_all()
            display.insert(0, "Error")

    def fact():
        entire_string = display.get()
        try:
            result = factorial(int(entire_string))
            clear_all()
            display.insert(0, result)
        except Exception:
            clear_all()
            display.insert(0, "Error")

    display = Entry(frmcalc)
    display.grid(row=1, columnspan=6, sticky=N + E + W + S)

    Button(frmcalc, width="10",height = "5", text="1", command=lambda: get_variables(1)).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, width="10",height = "5",text=" 2", command=lambda: get_variables(2)).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, width="10",height = "5",text=" 3", command=lambda: get_variables(3)).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=N + S + E + W)

    Button(frmcalc, width="10",height = "5",text="4", command=lambda: get_variables(4)).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, text=" 5", command=lambda: get_variables(5)).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, text=" 6", command=lambda: get_variables(6)).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=N + S + E + W)

    Button(frmcalc, width="10",height = "5",text="7", command=lambda: get_variables(7)).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, text=" 8", command=lambda: get_variables(8)).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, text=" 9", command=lambda: get_variables(9)).grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=N + S + E + W)

    Button(frmcalc, width="10",height = "5",text="AC", command=lambda: clear_all()).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, text=" 0", command=lambda: get_variables(0)).grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, text=" .", command=lambda: get_variables(".")).grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=N + S + E + W)

    Button(frmcalc, width="5",height = "5",text="+", command=lambda: get_operation("+")).grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, text="-", command=lambda: get_operation("-")).grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, text="*", command=lambda: get_operation("*")).grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, text="/", command=lambda: get_operation("/")).grid(row=5, column=3, sticky=N + S + E + W)

    Button(frmcalc, width="5",text="pi", command=lambda: get_operation("*3.14")).grid(row=2, column=4, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, text="%", command=lambda: get_operation("%")).grid(row=3, column=4, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, text="(", command=lambda: get_operation("(")).grid(row=4, column=4, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, text="exp", command=lambda: get_operation("**")).grid(row=5, column=4, sticky=N + S + E + W)

    Button(frmcalc, width="5",height = "5",text="<-", command=lambda: undo()).grid(row=2, column=5, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, text="x!", command=lambda: fact()).grid(row=3, column=5, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, text=")", command=lambda: get_operation(")")).grid(row=4, column=5, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, text="^2", command=lambda: get_operation("**2")).grid(row=5, column=5, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, text="^2", command=lambda: get_operation("**2")).grid(row=5, column=5, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    Button(frmcalc, width="5",height = "5",text="=", command=lambda: calculate()).grid(columnspan=6, sticky=N + S + E + W)
```

Comment: You would get a lot more information if you logged the entire error, rather than just outputting the meaningless message "Error11" in the last line.

Comment: @rici hope this can help you better, thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Your sample code is not a complete script that shows the problem when run. A complete script would presumably include:

- An invocation of `calculate`.
- Definition or import of `display` and `clear_all` and `parse`.

If the problem is with the `parse` object, it's especially important to know what that is / how it's defined. (Mind you, there isn't enough info here to know that `parse` is indeed the problem.)

(2) As @rici indicated, if you change the `except` block to something like:

```
  except Exception as e:
      clear_all()
      display.insert(0, e)
```

you'll get output that is more informative to both you and anyone attempting to help you.

---

[After the above info was filled in...]

Okay, you're importing a module named `parse`, and then calling the function `parse.expr`, but the error message is telling you that there is no such function in the `parse` module, so you get an Exception when you try to call it.

`parse` doesn't appear to be a standard Python module (I don't see it listed [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html)), so I can't help you much more. You may need to go back to whoever/whatever told you to use it, or find some documentation for it.

Or maybe you meant `parser`. (`import parser` and then `parser.expr`)

Comment: tried that = "module 'parse' has no attribute 'expr'"

Comment: Okay, I've added to my answer.

Comment: lolol it was parser not parse.... godddd, thanks :)